Are moving or transport questions on topic?
Bizarrely, this isn't the first time I've seen a question asking how to build a custom hoist. That's not the approach I'd take in the first place, so it's something of an XY question. It's also not home improvement, in my opinion, as it's a temporary structure for a specific task.
I need a temporary hoist and track system to lift a dead chest freezer up through a tight stairwell
Let's broaden the scope a bit to moving in or out and transporting large things. Are they within our scope? Here are some others:

Moving a used refrigerator
Moving a washer and dryer when relocating across the country
A-Frame for a hoist?
Removing a stuck washing machine

What criteria should be considered when deciding the relevance of such questions? If the project is clearly temporary (short term), is it home improvement?
